# How to use System enviroment Variables in Eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, environment-variables, eclipse-cdt

I appended to my .bashrc file the following lines:

```
SYSTEMC="/usr/local/systemc-2.3.1/"
SYSTEMC_INCLUDE="/usr/local/systemc-2.3.1/includes"
SYSTEMC_LIBS="/usr/local/systemc-2.3.1/lib-linux"
```

and I can do this in my terminal:

```
$ echo $SYSTEMC
/usr/local/systemc-2.3.1/
```

So everything here looks fine.

Now I added in `Eclipse Project properties->c/C++ build->settings->GCC C++ Compiler->Include`
this: $(SYSTEMC_INCLUDE)

The resulting makefile contains this line:

```
g++ -I$(SYSTEMC_INCLUDE) -O0...
```

But if I run this and look in the console the SYSTEMC_INCLUDE var seems to be empty:

```
g++ -I -O0 ....
```

What can I do to propagate my system enviroment variables to Eclipse?
Is it because .bashrc is only for the shell? Should I export them somewhere else?
Should I add the export statements in the .bashrc file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, .bashrc is only used when a user opens a bash shell. Since you're on linux, to export environment variables system wide (and by extension to GUI applications), use /etc/environment.

Comment: the env var resolving works now... but eclipse has still problem with showing the includes... Make uses the right commands, but the Include drop down menu in eclipse shows rubbish